# Filling nulls with a list in Pandas using fillna

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series, missing-data, fillna

Given a `pd.Series`, I would like to replace null values with a list. That is, given:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series([0,1,np.nan])
```

I want a function that would return

```
0        0
1        1
2    [nan]
```

But if I try using the natural function for this, namely [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
result = ser.fillna([np.nan])
```

but I get the error

> TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar or dict, but you passed a "list"

Any suggestions of a simple way to acheive this?

Comment: This is bug , https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3435, BTW, why you need this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `apply`, because `fillna` working with scalars only:

```
print (ser.apply(lambda x: [np.nan] if pd.isnull(x) else x))
0        0
1        1
2    [nan]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change to object

```
ser=ser.astype('object')
```

Then assign the list `np.nan`

```
ser.loc[ser.isnull()]=[[np.nan]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using

```
ser.loc[ser.isnull()] = ser.loc[ser.isnull()].apply(lambda x: [np.nan])
```

because pd.isnull(x) would give me ambiguous truth values error ( i have other lists in my series too ). This is a combination of YOBEN_S' and jezrael's answer.

Answer (score 0):

[fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) can take a Series, and a list can be converted to a Series. Wrapping your list in `pd.Series()` worked for me:

```
result = ser.fillna(pd.Series([np.nan]))

result
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: The question explicitly asks for a list as value at index 2. So should be [nan] instead of NaN.